# unix network programming

Tags: c, unix, network-programming

I want to send the two different packets in different port numbers parallely using UDP.
Can I achive this using single socket() or should I create another socket??
Can anbody give me some idea on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single socket, you will be using the system calls `sendto(2)` and `recvfrom(2)` to send and receive data over the datagram sockets.

Take a look at https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/syscalls.html for more information (the entire guide is definitely worth the read).

[Beej's guide on socket programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/syscalls.html)

Comment: I'll second that, Beej's guide has been indispensable for me!